# Is there a standard name for a set equipped only with an idempotent binary operation?

Tags: terminology, universal-algebra, idempotents, magma

Is there a name for an idempotent magma, or do they not arise often enough to warrant a special name?

(By idempotent binary operation, I mean an operation $+$ such that $x + x = x$ for any $x$.)

Comment: I doubt you will do better than idempotent magma.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comment by @James answers this question: a magma/groupoid $(G,+)$ where
$$x+x=x\quad\forall x\in G,$$
this is where every element is idempotent, is called *idempotent groupoid*, or *idempotent magma* if you prefer.

Examples in the titles (and bibliographies) of [this article](http://dml.cz/bitstream/handle/10338.dmlcz/102456/CzechMathJ_41-1991-2_5.pdf) or [this thesis](http://lib.dr.iastate.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=4292&context=etd).

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't seem to be a very interesting definition on its face; classification is pretty trivial: Given any set $S$, the idempotent binary operations $S \times S \to S$ are given by those functions which send $(x, x)$ to $x$ and behave arbitrarily on $(S \times S)-\Delta$, the nondiagonal elements.

Of course if you pile on a few additional axioms you might get something interesting, or maybe if you start examining relationships between different idempotent binary operations. I haven't heard of this kind of object being defined on its own though.

Comment: It's useful for a formal development I'm doing in Agda. Idempotence is preserved (in isolation) by functors such as `Maybe` ($= A \mapsto 1 + A$) so I'd like to have a name for structures that just provide a single idempotent operation. `IdempotentMagma` is a bit of a mouthful :)